# How to install VirtualBox extension pack?

Tags: virtualbox

I downloaded the extension pack from:
https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

Got this file `Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-5.2.14.vbox-extpack.gz`

To install it you have to go to `File / Preferences / Extensions / Add` In there, it expects you to add a file with the extension `vbox-extpack`.

Double clicking the file extracts it to a folder without the extension. So, I went to the CLI and did:

```
gunzip Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-5.2.14.vbox-extpack.gz
```

That resulted in what seemed to be the right file, but when I tried to add it to VirtualBox I got the error:

```
Failed to open the Extension Pack /Users/givanse/Downloads/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-5.2.14.vbox-extpack.

RTZipGzipDecompressIoStream failed: VERR_ZIP_BAD_HEADER
```

Comment: Odd, when I download it on a Mac or a windows PC I get the file without the GZ file extension. What if you just remove the file extension and double-click on the resultant downloaded file. That *should* just open VBox with a warning about "you are about to install...."

Comment: That was the clue! I was downloading the file with Brave browser and it wasn't decompressing the file. So I went on to download the file with Chrome and it gave me the `.vbox-extpack` that was needed.

Comment: Brave bug report: https://github.com/brave/browser-laptop/issues/14757